# How to calculate hours in mysql

Tags: mysql

My problem is in brief here...

Once a user signed in i stored his login date in the users table. If the user doesn't logged in for 72 hours i need to change his status to inactive.

**How can i able to find whether 72 hours is completed or not after the user logged in using My Sql.**

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend using the TIMEDIFF() function, which you can find documented here:
[dev.mysql.com timediff doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff).

In your case, I'd format my where clause something like this:

```
WHERE
TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(), LastLoginDate) > '3 0:0:0.0'
```

or

```
WHERE
TIMEDIFF(CURTIME(), LastLoginDate) > '72:0:0.0'
```

I haven't done this specifically, but the base concept should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Create a CRON routine to run every hour with this query:

```
  UPDATE users
  SET status = 'Inactive' 
  WHERE (SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_login < now() - 259200)
```

To answer your question more specifically, it is the where clause, when ran, that tells you all the users that haven't logged in for 72 hours.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE last_login < now() - 259200
```

However, there is no way to set each user to inactive at **exactly** 72 hours. To get more accurate than the solution provided above, run the query more often.

*Note - insert your columns names where appropriate. Query not tested. 259200 = # of seconds in 72 hours - assumes you store your timestamps seconds (Epoch)

Answer (score 0):

Use [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) type to store dates, subtract 72 hours from [NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) using [DATE_SUB()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) and see if the result is larger than the value stored in the database.